# Find probability of the given data set, what probability i can say it is bad

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a issue where there is a data set. and in there i have good and bad category, and in that category there are few elements that can be good and bad....

you can see the ven diagram i attached to get a view and the data set i have. please ill be really glad if you could help me out.

[image]
[image]

I am really new to probability and math stuff, yet i have a project to do where in the middle i have to find a way to say the given data set is bad or good depending on the data.

what probability theory can i use?
How to use... please give an an example using my data set. thankyou

Eg. if i get a data set of A,D,E elements are there... what probability i can say it is bad.

Comment: did you try naive bayes approach ?

Comment: IMHO, this is more suitable for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes.... if you are considering machine learning. But also i did use P(B|A u B)... but there i get a probability more than one. which im not sure if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

A function which gives a good / bad result is called a classification function. For any data set, there are many ways to construct a classification function. See, for example, "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" by Brian Ripley.

One way which is easy to understand is the so-called quadratic discriminant. It is easy to describe: (1) construct a Gaussian density for each category (good, bad, etc). (2) output the category for which a new input has the greatest probability.

(1) just compute the mean and covariance matrix for the data in each category. That gives you p(x | category).

(2) choose category such that p(category | x) is greatest. Note p(category | x) = p(x | category) p(category) / sum_i (p(x | category_i) p(category_i)), where p(category) is just (number of data in category) / (number of all data). If you work with logarithms, you can simplify the calculations somewhat.

Such a function can be constructed in a very few lines of a programming language which has matrix operations, such as Octave or R.